# Sci-fi short story about why you only find one shoe on the road

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for the name and author of a science fiction short story about why you only ever find one shoe on the side of the road.

- Hot babe picks up hitchhiker in a nice sports car.
- Hot babe turns into alien monster and EATS hitchhiker.
- Throws one shoe out window.

Comment: Welcome to the site. In which year did you read this story, and in what format (magazine, anthology book, online)? Also, do you have any idea which decade it was published in?

Comment: I was a teenager. I'm 48 now. It was one of those sci fi mags. I don't remember anything else about it

Comment: So, late 80's. Do you think it was an old magazine? Small (Analog) or large (Omni) format?

Comment: What did the monster do with the other shoe?

Comment: It doesn't say. Car speeds off. The end.

Comment: Something like that. Asimov mag or something similar. It was many years ago. Could have been an anthology for all I know. Just don't remember.

Comment: Sounds like a variation of the old joke about "waiting for the other shoe to drop." That joke was current in the 1940s, so it wouldn't be unlikely for an author to use it in the 50s or 60s.

Answer (score 11):

This is definitely Ron Wolfe's "[The One-Shoe Blues](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42654)" (1985). It can be read in its original context [online courtesy of the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v09n11_1985-11/page/n123/mode/2up).

> He looked toward Lyn again. She was driving like before, tapping out
> the rhythm of the "One-Shoe Blues" on the car top.
>
> At the same time, Charlie couldn't help noticing, she had both hands
> on the wheel.
>
> He fingered the door latch.
>
> "Suppose," she said, "suppose... there is no monster, Charlie. But
> suppose there is a... very different kind of life, from a different
> kind of place. Lost here, through no fault of its own. And it can
> change shapes, like on 'Star Trek.' Suppose... it could not make you
> understand how it does that, except to that it *breathes* in the
> feelings all around it."

It's not the protagonist that gets eaten, but another hitchhiker after the protagonist's escape.

> He turned just in time to catch a glimpse of the candy apple Corvette.
> There were bits of glitter in the paint finish. The girl driving it
> wasn't wearing any top at all that Charlie could see, and her hair was
> done up in a blond swirly-cue like Dolly Parton.
>
> ...
>
> The car sped past him, and was almost out of sight when Charlie saw
> the driver toss out something small and brown.
>
> ...
>
> Before long, he found the other shoe.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll check it out. Not sure but probably lol. My memory of it is probably inaccurate after all these years.

Comment: Just looked. That's definitely the one! Has it been collected into any anthologies?

Comment: @Joe Parato - If this answer is correct, please mark it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Thanks.

Comment: @JoeParato, according to ISFDB, no.